Restriction of back bonding in tris(dimethylamino)borane
J.D. Lee Concise Inorganic Chemistry [3, p. 78] mentions that

The bond length order of the B-N bond in the following compounds is
$\ce{B(NR2)3}$ > $\ce{HB(NR2)2}$ > $\ce{H2B(NR2)}$
and the order of energy required for the rotation of the B-N bond is just reverse, i.e.
$\ce{H2B(NR2)}$ > $\ce{HB(NR2)2}$ > $\ce{B(NR2)3}$
Here the back bonding from N to B is most restricted in case of $\ce{B(NR2)3}$ due to steric crowding and most relaxed in case of $\ce{H2B-NR2}$. Hence, the above orders are well explained.

Here, from the above statement what I analyzed is as follows-
1)Due to steric crowding between bulky $\ce{NR2}$ groups, they rotate in the perpendicular plane and therefore, the lone pair on nitrogen atom is unavailable to back bond with the vacant orbital of boron.
2)And as we replace those $\ce{NR2}$ groups by hydrogen, steric crowding reduces, thereby increasing the planarity of the compound and increasing extent of back bonding. That is maximum in $\ce{H2B(NR2)}$ and due to more efficient back bonding there is more double bond character and lesser bond length.
3)Hence, we will require more energy to be supplied for rotation of B-N bond in the compound which has the most double bond character and less energy for rotation of B-N bond in the compound with more single bond character.
Is my logic correct?

This is the second question of yours where the reference counter for some reason starts at 3 and there is no reference to this pointer. Why?

Sorry, I'm new here can you please tell me what you mean by "starts at 3" and what the pointer is?

The first number in [3, p. 78] is supposed to be the pointer to the literature reference, which is absent. The numbering is usually sequential in the order of references appearing, and starts with 1.

okay thanks for information

I deleted my answer. Your reasoning is totally correct, given that R is methyl. Other even bulkier R groups may introduce restricted rotation for very different reason. I forgot to pay enough attention to the title.

@PaulKolk Alright, thanks for confirming
